# How to link to an Excel cell via URL

Tags: excel

I've uploaded an Excel sheet to our website, but I want to be able to link to a particular row/cell within that sheet, so when people open it, they are taken to that row/cell straight away. Is this possible?

I tried using www.website.co.uk/test.xlsx#Sheet1!A7 but that doesn't appear to work.
I need to be able to link it from a Google Map comment box into a row/cell so it's leaving it fairly limited.

I would have used Google Sheets, but it's blocked by our IT department unfortunately.

Comment: You could create a workbook open event?

Comment: Will users be downloading this ?

Comment: Yes, users will be downloading this, so not sure a Workbook Open Event will work? I basically need to link into 200 different cells from 200 different locations!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, for workbooks that are downloaded, you could try a workbook open event. Also provided users can run macros.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Evaluate("ISREF('Sheet1'!A1)") Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Activate
            .Range("A7").Activate
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above goes in the pane for ThisWorkbook.

Comment: Thanks, users will be downloading this, so not sure a Workbook Open Event will work? I basically need to link into 200 different cells from 200 different locations!

Comment: It will work if users downloading. You can use select case to determine which range is activated on open.